# Clickable component to make AJAX Call that isn't a Submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

pretty new JS/JQuery programmer here so please forgive any oversights/poorly worded text.  Similarly, all feedback is appreciated even if it's not specifically requested.

I have a few drop down lists which are dynamically populated by data in SQL Tables.  I have a setup whereby if the user selects "Other," a text field appears below the DDL to allow entry of a custom value.  These custom values should be added to the DB so they show up in the DDLs.  Since there are a lot of these DDLs on the page, I want the DB update and DDL update to happen right away (on user click) rather than after filling out the whole page and doing it on page submit (this also makes it easier to debug because there are a lot of required fields).

So my code so far looks like this:

```
<label for="IDIQs">Associated IDIQ/BPA:</label>
<select id="IDIQs" required>
</select>
<br>

<div id="IDIQs_other_div" class="other_field">
<label for="IDIQs_other">Other IDIQ/BPA:</label><br><input type="text"      name="IDIQs_other" id="IDIQs_other" size="50" required/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Contract Vehicle Type to Database" name="IDIQs_other_submit"  onClick='updateDB("IDIQs");'> 
</div>
```

Which obviously doesn't work because this input type is interpreted by the browser to mean it's a submit button for the whole form.

What's the easiest/best practice way to make this happen?

Note that the "nice to have" feature would be to have the newly entered value be the selected value in the DDL once everything's said and done.

I use JQuery in this page as well as regular JavaScript.

Comment: Use a button, not submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `<input type="button" />` or an anchor styled to look like a button or really anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

i recommended to use button, not submit

```
<input type="button" value="Add Contract Vehicle Type to Database" name="IDIQs_other_submit"  onClick='updateDB("IDIQs");'>
```

Always when you click on this button then `ajax` function will be call

Answer (score 0):

Use the `on` function in jQuery to trigger the ajax.

```
$('.yourElement').on('click', function(e) {
    // Your Ajax code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this:

1) Add a class on the html tags that you want instant submit

2) We will submit what the user types when he focuses someplace else( blur event )

```
$('.class').blur(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $.thrim($this.val());

    if ($.thrim($this.val()) !== '') { // we dont want to submit blanks for no reason
        var request = $.ajax({
          url: "script.php",    // path of your php script
          type: "POST", 
          data: {key : val},
          dataType: "json"
        });

        request.done = function(reply) { // success get a reply maybe from server
            console.log(reply)
        }

        request.fail = function(err) {  some error occured
            console.log(err)
        }

    }

})
```